# counting occurance of an alphabet in a list

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python to count number of times an alphabet occurs in a given sequence using list comprehension

For example:

```
countoccur("s", "ssssdfrtsgjdt" )
```

should give 5 as output since s occurs five times. I wrote this code and get the following output:

```
def countoccur(x,s):
    y=[e for e in s if e==x]
    return y
```

output:

```
['s', 's', 's', 's', 's']
```

can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Python has better tools but if you want to keep your code, Just return the len of `y`:

```
def countoccur(x,s):
    y=[e for e in s if e==x]
    return len(y)
```

Outout:

```
output: 5
```

You can also use [count()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm):

```
print string.count('s')
```

or [findall()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
print len(re.findall("s", string))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the builtin [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) function, like this

```
def countoccur(char, input_string):
    return input_string.count(char)

print countoccur("s", "ssssdfrtsgjdt" )
```

I would suggest using a generator expression and [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function like this

```
return sum(1 for e in input_string if e == char)
```

This can be shortened to the following, as @volcano suggested in the comments

```
return sum(e == char for e in input_string)
```

This works because, in Python, `True == 1` and `False == 0` :)

If you want to use only comprehension,

```
return sum([e == char for e in input_string])
```

Comment: @volcano Indeed :) Because `True == 1` and `False == 0` in Python :)

Comment: @thefourtheye exactly.

Comment: You should add link to `str.count` not `string.count`. :-)

Comment: @volcano Thanks man :) Added your suggestion in the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Python really comes with all the batteries included, try using [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: s="ssssdfrtsgjdt"

In [3]: Counter(s)
Out[3]: Counter({'s': 5, 'd': 2, 't': 2, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'j': 1, 'r': 1})

In [4]: Counter(s)['s']
Out[4]: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

To write a Counter manually as Fredrik Pihl mentioned:

```
In [60]: from collections import defaultdict
    ...: cnt=defaultdict(int)
    ...: s="ssssdfrtsgjdt"
    ...: for v in s:
    ...:    cnt[v]+=1
    ...: 

In [61]: print cnt['s'], cnt['d']
5 2
```